# How SQL Server local account password rotation impact active user

Tags: sql-server

Description: We are using SQL Server local account to connect to database in our .net core app hosted in AWS Lambda.

Question: We have policy that we need rotate local account password every several months. I want to know if there is any impact to active user who has already been connected to db with the local account after changing password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be tested as follows:

Create a login

```
CREATE LOGIN ChangeMe WITH PASSWORD = '!57r0ng_'
```

Login as that SQL login in another SSMS window

in the original window where we created the login, change the password

```
ALTER LOGIN ChangeMe WITH PASSWORD = '!57r0ng_2'
```

Go back to the window logged in as ChangeMe and see if we can run something:

```
SELECT 1
```

Success

Therefore only new connections will be affected by the change